# Would "same-origin cookies" make sense?

Tags: cookies, same-origin-policy, same-site-cookies

I have read [Incrementally Better Cookies](https://mikewest.github.io/cookie-incrementalism/draft-west-cookie-incrementalism.html), a couple of web.dev articles and tried to google for "same-origin cookies" but could not find anything so I wonder if this is being worked on.

`SameSite=Strict` & `Lax` are a [very good protection against CSRF](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121971/will-same-site-cookies-be-sufficent-protection-against-csrf-and-xss) but hacked subdomains remain a way to attack – for example, `hacked.example.com` can forge credentialed requests to `example.com` easily.

I would imagine that restricting cookies further, from same-site to same-origin, would be a logical next step. What is being worked on is [schemeful same-site](https://web.dev/schemeful-samesite/) (distinguishing `http://` vs. `https://` when considering what is same-site) but why not use the concept of origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would definitely make sense and there is a [proposition](https://github.com/sbingler/Origin-Bound-Cookies) about this (Origin Bound cookies).

> SameSite=Strict & Lax are a very good protection against CSRF but hacked subdomains remain a way to attack – for example, hacked.example.com can forge credentialed requests to example.com easily.

Fot this, you can actually use the `__Host-` [cookie prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#cookie_prefixes). On browsers with [support](https://caniuse.com/?search=cookie%20prefix) for cookie prefixes, it is not possible to set them across domains: this way your are sure that the cookie actually comes from example.com and not hacked.example.com.

However, there is currently no way to bind a cookie to a (domain, port) pair. As I'm discussing on [a bug entry](https://github.com/httpwg/http-extensions/issues/1526), this is especially problematic for localhost-bound non-HTTPS web server: another local user can exfiltrate your cookies by spawning a local server on another port and tricking you into browser to this web server.

Comment: Excellent, thank you, "Origin-Bound-Cookies" is what I failed to find. Great!

Comment: You do have the ‘SECURE’ keyword limiting its use to only HTTPS (especially if combined with the __secure prefix) see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie

Comment: @LvB, not sure what you bean by this. __Host is strictly more "strict" than __Secure has it implies the same things are __Strict. Concerning the exfiltration of localhost-bound cookies, using HTTPS is indeed an option (but usually those services are usually not using HTTPS).

Comment: __HOST does not say anything about the connection type, __SECURE does… but who one to pick is a implementatie detail. (But having a __SECUREmy.example.com for my.example.com would vind said cookie to the domain (and it’s leafs) and to the protocol (HTTPS). The main caveat is the localhost exception. Finally I have heard no valid reason to not run TLS… (as of yet, in any case).

Comment: @LvB, the prefix is actually to the cookie **name**, not the domain name (eg. Set-Cookie: __Host-SID=12345; Secure; Path=/)

Comment: @LvB, see https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cookie-prefixes-00, “If a cookie's name begins with "__Host-", the **cookie MUST be: Set with a "Secure" attribute** […]”

Comment: @ysdx you are correct… I missed that.. sorry. (I only know it for the __SECURE prefix… Thank you for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @LvB, by the way, "secure" cookies actually work on http://127.0.0.1:* (and at least for Firefox "localhost", etc.) as it is considered a secure context, https://www.w3.org/TR/secure-contexts/#localhost https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-secure-contexts/issues/43

Comment: @ysdx From the MDN site
" Secure
    Cookie is only sent to the server when a request is made with the https: scheme
 (except on localhost), and therefore is more resistent to man-in-the-middle attacks."

So if this is true, its not conform there own Documentation.

Comment: @ysdx After reading the explainers [here](https://github.com/sbingler/Origin-Bound-Cookies#does-this-proposal-obsolete-schemeful-same-site) and [here](https://github.com/sbingler/schemeful-same-site#how-do-schemeful-same-site-and-scheme-bound-cookies-differ), I think that even the combination of Schemeful Same-Site and Origin-Bound Cookies don't prevent subdomain CSRF attacks – a hypothetical "Originful Same-Site" would (or the `__Host-` prefix as you said). So to renew the question, would it make sense to propose "Originful Same-Site"? Is there such proposal?

Comment: Origin-bound is designed to be more strict and supersede schemefule cookies AFAIU. The opt-out mechanism for origin-bound cookies would be toggled by passing a Domain argument. This parameter is forbidden in __Host- prefixed cookies. Thus, these cookies would be completely origin-bound under this proposal. Would you expect something else?

Comment: Origin-bound cookies are complementary to schemeful cookies as explained [here](https://github.com/sbingler/Origin-Bound-Cookies#does-this-proposal-obsolete-schemeful-same-site). Surprisingly to me, even the combination of both of them isn't enough to protect from subdomain attacks and the (relatively unknown) `__Host-` prefix needs to be used.

Comment: Also relevant, but never implemented by browsers: https://mikewest.github.io/internetdrafts/origin-cookies/draft-west-origin-cookies-00.html