# Is a static SameSite cookie enough to protect against CSRF?

Tags: cookies, csrf, same-site-cookies

Conventional wisdom to prevent CSRF is to use CSRF tokens, but with the new cookie attributes and prefixes, do you even need to generate/save tokens at all?

I've had the thought that if I just set a cookie with a static value, I can simply test for its existence, since SameSite ensures it won't be sent on cross-site requests, and the __Host- prefix prevents tampering via MITM and subdomain attacks.

```
Set-Cookie: __Host-AntiCSRF=yes; SameSite=Strict; Secure; Path=/
```

Would setting such a cookie fully protect me from CSRF, even if the value is static/guessable instead of a session token?

Comment: It strikes me that some older browsers don't support SameSite cookies so you still need to have a CSRF token in the form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will same-site cookies be sufficent protection against CSRF and XSS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/121971/129883)